# How to run FlashBuilder 4.7 on OSX with Java 1.7

Tags: java, ios, macos, flash-builder

FlashBuilder 4.7 is quite cool and ios integration is now much better, as it auto installs on device and debug over usb. You also now have the ability to either debug against an AIR device simulator which is the one that shipped standard with FB, or the iOS simulator that ships with XCode. And then if you were playing with workers, multi-threading is now much easier and more seamless due to the use of a more fancy tool. Etc...

However, FlashBuilder 4.7 only supports JDK 1.6. It seems to work ok, until I've attempted to run my mobile app on device. Removing JDK 1.7 from my system is not an option, since I'm coding java as well as flex. It took me a couple of hours to figure this out. Hope it can maybe save someone else some time. Any other additional comments / tips welcome

Answer (score 4):

As already noted, compiling for ios doesn't work with JDK1.7. So if you have a mac, and you installed JDK1.7, then you might want to to create a little shell script.
Mine is under: 
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/run.sh 
containing:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/"
/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7
```

Now, you might want to launch it from your dock, since running it from the terminal is a bit of a pain in the butt, so launch Automator and create new application. Call it FB4.7 or whatever you like. Next, in the top left search field, search for shell script. 
And in the right pane under "Run shell script", enter the following:

```
/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/run.sh
```

Right, now save the application under /Applications and drag it to your dock as you would any other application.

You might also want to run it using AIR3.5. I had some issues debugging ios over usb with the standard AIR sdk that ships with FB4.7, so in terminal, (note I don't use finder as finder replace the entire contents of the folder) execute the following:

```
cd /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/sdks/
cp -rv 4.6.0 4.6.0-Air3.5 
cp -rv ~/Downloads/air3-5_p4_sdk_asc2_mac_111912/* ./4.6.0-Air3.5/
# you might need to use appropriate path of wherever you put air3.5 after you copied / downloaded it
```

You might also need to quit FB if it is open and:

```
cd /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/
mv AIRSDK AIRSDK.old 
cp -rv /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/sdks/4.6.0-Air3.5 ./AIRSDK
```

I also found that in order for debugging to work you might have to go to iTunes and manually eject all devices except the one you are debugging on, of course

O, yes, in order to get it to work on the IOS  simulator I also had to go to xcode and install ios sdk5.0. Haven't really investigated how to run with newer ios sdk. Get an annoying popup each time I run simmulator whereby I have to select my sdk version, but that'll have to do for now

Happy coding

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but I recently ran into this issue and it took me some time to figure out a working solution.

I use *Flash Builder 4.7* on my mac with 2 java JDK folders:

- java *JDK 1.8.0*. This is the default JDK used by all other installations of Eclipse / Android Studio ..
- java *JDK 1.6.0*. This is just the JDK library folder.

You have to point to the 1.6.0 JRE in the *Flash Builder 4.7.ini* file. You can find the file in the Contents folder of Flash Builder app:

```
.../Adobe Flash Builder 4.7.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Flash Builder.ini
```

In that file, specify the path to bin folder of the JRE 1.6.0 with the -vm option. I think the -vm option need to come just before the -vmargs option. My complete .ini file looks like this:

```
-startup
../../../eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../../../eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
../../../assets/fb_splash_premium.png
-nl
en_US
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
-vmargs
-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:PermSize=64m
-Xdock:name=Flash Builder
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/fb_app.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Declipse.product=com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.producte36
-Declipse.application=com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.FlashBuilderApplication
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

When you start a new workspace, you might want to adjust the configured JRE in the Preferences of your workspace. I don't know if this step is necessary.

Flash Builder > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Add..

```
1. Select MacOS X VM as JRE Type
2. Enter the path to the JRE
```

[screenshot for entering the JRE path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4tkb.png)

```
3. Select the new JRE:
```

---

The suggested answer by Christo is not working for me. Flash Builder kept on launching with my latest java jdk (1.8.0), which resulted in startup errors.

---

I also tried the solution given by adobe in 2016: http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2016/09/running-adobe-flash-builder-on-mac-with-java-78.html#sthash.sqbeFw8g.dpbs

With that solution from adobe you can indeed launch Flash Builder 4.7 that uses jdk8, but you will run into build errors as soon as you try to use prebuilded libs into one of your flex projects.